# Can't see logback logs in log4j configured embeded Jetty application

Tags: java, logback, log4j2, embedded-jetty, logback-groovy

In my java application I have embedded a jetty and I'm using log4j2 for my logging. When I deploy war files which use log4j2 as its logging mechanism I can see logs. But problem arise when I deploy war files which use logback as logging mechanism, because I can't get logs.

Comment: The question doesn't provide enough details to be able to guess what causes the problem with Logback. Why not just use Log4j 2, if that works?

Comment: actually in my application what I intend to do is deploy different web applications same as in  jetty or tomcat. Recently i got a war file which use logback for logging. So I can't change logging mechanism in my war file(web application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [which jars you need](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars):

If you add the log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar and remove the logback jars then all Logback logging will be included in the Log4j 2 log.

I assume you already have the slf4j-api jar in the classpath. Keep that, but replace the Logback jars with the log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar.